# Trie storing string at the end of branch exceeds call stack limit

Tags: javascript, algorithm, trie

When you build a trie, do you store the string / sentence at the end of its branch to easily access it at the end of the branch? Some people do and I do sometimes but should I?

Sometimes (especially with LeetCode), I get this error:

```
Line # in solution.js
AutocompleteSystem.prototype.dfs = function(root, char, foundStrings) {
                                           ^
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

The error just means I've exceeded the call stack for my depth-first search function.

There's nothing else I changed other than my Trie class:

```js
class Trie {
    constructor() {
        this.root = {};
        this.end = '#';
    }

    insert(sentence, times) {
        let current = this.root;
        for (const char of sentence) {
            if (current[char] == null) {
                current[char] = {};
            }
            current = current[char];
        }
        current[this.end] = true; // This works fine, submission accepted.
        // If I store the string here like so:
        // current[this.end] = sentence; I get the error.
        current.times = current.times + 1 || times;
    }
}

// As you can see, the dfs function won't affect 
// if I store the string at the end of each branch or not 
// because it doesn't use the value of #
const dfs = function(root, char, foundStrings) {
    for (const key in root) {
        // If reach the end of a branch:
        if (key === '#') {
            // If the current times not already in foundStrings:
            if (!foundStrings[root.times]) {
                // Initiate an empty array with the new times as key
                // to store strings later:
                foundStrings[root.times] = [];
            }
            // Else, push the found string into foundStrings, grouped by times:
            foundStrings[root.times].push(char);
            // Sort all strings in the same group:
            foundStrings[root.times].sort();
        }
        // Keep searching:
        this.dfs(root[key], char + key, foundStrings);
    }
}
```

The Trie class just builds a trie from the `string[]: sentences` and I don't do anything else with the end symbol `#` so there's no other error.

Comment: **do you store the string at the end of its branch?** No. That would break the whole point of building a Trie (which is to save space not storing repeated characters). The best thing to do is to keep a string that holds the word (starting from the root) until the node you are at. Obviously, depending on the situation (input size), you can afford to save the whole word in the leafs of the trie, but I wouldn't recomend it.

Comment: Thank you. What you wrote makes sense. Some people do throw the chars into the recursive function and update it and return it at the end of the dfs, but some just store the string at the end.

Comment: Since the error occurs in `dfs` it might be useful to know what that function looks like.

Comment: I've added the `dfs` function above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mark the end of a word by storing a special sentinel key `'#'` in the objects that make up the nodes of your tree. The values associated with the keys are the descendant nodes for the next letter, but the value associated with the sentinel key is a string.

In your depth-first search, you iterate over all keys in a node and if the key is the sentinel, you add the word you have constructed so far. But then you also recurse down the sentinel key and pass in the string as new root node. In the next recursion, the loop

```
for (const key in root) ...
```

iterates over the characters of the string, which enumerates its characters:

```
{0: 't', 1: 'r', 2: 'i', 3: 'e'}
```

The next recursion will iterate over the characters, that is over the single-letter strings. And so forth. The excessive recursion does not come from the trie, but when you accidentially leave the trie and recurse into strings.

If you use just `true` as your value for the sentinel key, there is nothing to iterate over, so you don't get the problem.

The solution is to recurse only if the key isn't the sentinel:

```
for (const key in root) {
    if (key === '#') {
        // add found string to list ...
    } else {
        this.dfs(root[key], char + key, foundStrings);
    }
}
```

(By the way, there is no harm in storing a string as end marker per se. You can usually construct a word from the path through the trie, but consider a trie that stores digits of a [T9 dictionary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T9_(predictive_text)), where you might want to store a list of valid words at the end nodes.)

Comment: Thank you so much! Your answer is very clear! I get it now.